# If a power of a prime number say $p^r$ does not divide $n!$ then $\frac{n}{p^r}<1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm busy with a proof with $p-adic$ numbers and I need to show that if

$p^r\nmid n! \implies \frac{n}{p^r} < 1$ where $p$ is prime.

I need this to show $\lfloor \frac{n}{p^r} \rfloor = 0$

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You need to show that $\frac{n}{p^r} < 1$ or $n < p^r$. If $n \geq p^r$, then we would have a factor $p^r$ in $n!$ and we would have $p^r \mid n!$.

Comment: So simple, I should have started with a proof by contradiction :D you are a nobleman and a scholar, I thank you sir.

Comment: @Henry Minor note: this is really a proof by contra- *positive*.